# C++11 static cast to rvalue reference

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference, static-cast

A friend of mine wrote some code similar to this in a project:

```
struct A {
  int x{0};
};

struct B : public A {
  int y{1};
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b = static_cast<B &&>(a);
}
```

IMO, this code is clearly flawed and I confirmed it by trying to access `b.y` and running the program under Valgrind (which reported a memory error).
What I do not understand is why this is even compiling (I am using g++4.9.3). I was actually expecting an error message along the lines of `no matching function for call to B::B(A &&)`. I apologize if this is a stupid remark but how is it essentially different from writing `B b = static_cast<B>(a)` - which does give me a compile error? The only difference I see is copy from `A` to `B` vs move from `A` to `B`, and both of them are undefined here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `static_cast` from an lvalue of type `A` to `B &&` can be valid:

```
B b;
A &a = b;
B b2 = static_cast<B &&>(a);
```

The conversion is available, is not rejected by the compiler, because it could under other circumstances be valid. Yes, you're right, in your case it's definitely not valid.

> I was actually expecting an error message along the lines of `no matching function for call to B::B(A &&)`.

You would get an error along those lines (but not exactly that) if you used `std::move(a)`. By not having to spell out the type, it reduces the possibility of errors.

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer. Your example makes perfect sense to me because it is a situation where `std::move` cannot be used and you have to use a `static_cast` to the derived class.